# CSS for IE Input Field

Tags: html, css

In Firefox the text inside my input field is perfectly aligned in that it has the same spacing between the top and the bottom of the input box.  In IE it is shifted all the way to the top of the input field.  In one of my IE style sheets I added some code as seen below to shift it down, but when I do that it increases the input field's height by maintaining the same padding below the text.  Does anyone know of a way I can fix this so that the height stays the same while shifting the text down?

FYI - %BIND(:2) is the text

IE StyleSheet:

```
#searchfield {
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onchange="clickclear(this,'%BIND(:2)');" onclick="clickclear(this,'%BIND(:2)')" class="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="%BIND(:2)" name="SEARCH_TEXT" style="height:100%; min-height:40px; width:305px; padding:0 0 0 5px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:18px; font-style:normal;" />
```

Comment: Try to use `line-height`

Comment: a line-height of 200% worked.  I don't know if that is the best solution, but it worked.  I don't know why IE has to be so difficult.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this just an issue with IE<9? Im having trouble reproducing it in IE>9

Comment: I can't even run JSFiddle in IE8!!!

Comment: Why can't they seriously just get rid of Internet Explorer?  It's inferior to Chrome and Firefox for web users and it's a pain in the a$$ for web developers